# How to open a custom dialog on alarm time reached?

Tags: android, alarm

On alarm time reached i want to open a custom alert dialog

```
/* main class*/
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TimePicker myTimePicker;
Button buttonstartSetDialog;
TextView textAlarmPrompt;

TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

final static int RQS_1 = 1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textAlarmPrompt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);

    buttonstartSetDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
    buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
textAlarmPrompt.setText("");
openTimePickerDialog(false);

}});

}

private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r){
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
MainActivity.this, 
onTimeSetListener, 
calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 
is24r);
timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");  

timePickerDialog.show();

}

OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener
= new OnTimeSetListener(){

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
//Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

setAlarm(calSet);
}};

private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

textAlarmPrompt.setText(
"\n\n***\n"
+ "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
+ "***\n");

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}

}

/*recieving class*/
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "my activity";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Log.v(TAG,"my"+arg0);
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(arg0);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alarm);
dialog.show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must open your custom dialog on **onReceive** method in your AlarmReceiver class.

How implement your custom dialog: [http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayouthttp://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout)